# How to copy MyDocuments files into newly created folder?

Tags: vbscript, file-copying

Ok, so I have a perfectly running script... minus the fact that it does not truly copy the files/folders from my MyDocuments into my new folder. I have rack my brain over and over through this and have tried a few different commands to see if it would work. It copies over the Documents folder with Mymusic folder inside but not the folder and file I have selectively placed in there. Below is the script I currently have setup...

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWShell, userName, objFso, Wshshell, strDocuments, strLocation

Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objWShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

userName = objWShell.expandEnvironmentStrings("%userName%")

If Not objFso.FolderExists("C:\" + "Backups\") Then
  objFso.CreateFolder ("C:\" + "Backups\")
End If

If Not objFso.FolderExists("C:\Backups\" + userName +"\") Then
  objFso.CreateFolder ("C:\Backups\" + userName + "\")
End If

strDocuments = ("C:\Users\" + userName +"\Documents")

strLocation = ("C:\Backups\" + userName + "\")

If objFso.FolderExists (strDocuments) Then
  objFso.CopyFolder strDocuments, strLocation, True
End If
```

Comment: It's almost certainly failing with an access denied error. If you browse to your documents location via windows explorer and try to double click on "My Music", does it let you access it?

Comment: Unfortunately I am able to freely access MyMusic and MyDocuments. I have no music but two old playlists when I used to have music on my computer... Does this perhaps work for anyone else without a permissions denied??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to my problem is adding a "\" at the end of the referenced folders as well as the CopyFolder command. As I am away from my scripting computer at this time can anyone confirm my findings?

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWShell, userName, objFso, Wshshell, strDocuments, strLocation

Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Set objWShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

userName = objWShell.expandEnvironmentStrings("%userName%")

If Not objFso.FolderExists("C:\" + "Backups" + "\") Then    
  objFso.CreateFolder ("C:\" + "Backups" + "\")     
End If

If Not objFso.FolderExists("C:\Backups\" + userName +"\") Then    
  objFso.CreateFolder ("C:\Backups\" + userName + "\")    
End If

strDocuments = ("C:\Users\" + userName + "\" + "Documents"+ "\")    
strLocation = ("C:\Backups\" + userName + "\")

If objFso.FolderExists (strDocuments) Then    
  objFso.CopyFolder strDocuments, strLocation, True     
End If
```